# Prime numbers using sieve of erathosthenes

Tags: python

So I am new to programming in python(and in general) and was doing some coding challenges. I came across this 'prime numbers using the sieve method' challenge. I have successfully managed to attempt it however I feel like my logic needs improvement.

So what I did was use 3 while loops in python, the code works as intended, gives me a set of prime numbers however I cannot find a way to condense it.

```py
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])
ls = []
i = 2
while i <= n:
    ls.append(i)
    i += 1

i = 0
while i < len(ls):
    if i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        ls[i] = ''
    i += 2

i = 1
while i < len(ls):
    if i == 1:
        pass
    else:
        ls[i] = ''
    i += 3

i = 0
while i < len(ls):
    if i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        ls[i] = ''
    i += 5

i = 0
primes = []
while i < len(ls):
    if ls[i] != '':
        primes.append(ls[i])
    i += 1

for prime in primes:
    print(prime,end=', ')
```

As the ceo of nvidia once said, 'it just works' but clearly not in the best way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code thinks 49 is prime, which is not awesome.  Making a while loop for each prime just doesn't work.

Here's a simple version that does:

```
import math

def primesLessThan(N):
    seive = [True] * N
    seive[0] = seive[1] = False
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(N))+1):
        if (seive[i]):   # i is prime
            for j in range(2*i,N,i):   # all multiples of i >= 2i
                seive[j] = False       # j is composite since i is a factor
    return [p for p in range(2,N) if seive[p]]

print(primesLessThan(500))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question, why did you take the sqrt of N?. I'm still a little confused about the ranges that youre using. I'll appreciate if you explain the code to me. Cheers :D

Comment: If N = ab, then either a or b has to be <= sqrt(N), so to find all the composites you only need to mark off multiples of numbers <= sqrt(N)